# batch: ignore last line of an output

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a pretty basic script that echos local administrator accounts. My goal is to get rid of all of the header/footer information.

So far I have:

```
FOR /F "skip=6" %%G IN ('net localgroup administrators')  DO echo %%G
```

Which echos:

```
Administrator
MyName
The
```

"The" being the first word in the footer: "The command completed successfully."

So I'd like to get rid of "The" but I understand that I may have to restructure the entire script, which is fine. I have tried saving to a variable %str% but you can't set multi-line variables. Also, using a txt file as a buffer is not an option.

Any input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can think of two simple solutions:

```
FOR /F "skip=6" %%G IN ('net localgroup administrators')  DO if %%G neq The echo %%G
```

or

```
FOR /F "skip=6" %%G IN ('net localgroup administrators ^| findstr /vb The')  DO echo %%G
```

I suppose one could argue a user name could be "The", in which case you can be more precise with the filter:

```
FOR /F "skip=6" %%G IN ('net localgroup administrators ^| findstr /vc:"The command completed successfully."')  DO echo %%G
```